# git rebase, I think I'm doing something wrong

Tags: git

I'm working on a quite active project. To implement a new feature a create a new branch ("my-feature"). To keep track what is going on in master I do following steps from time to time:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout my-feature
git rebase master
```

At the beginning this worked quite well. But since a few days I have to go to many errors like:

```
stdin:28: trailing whitespace.

stdin:80: trailing whitespace.

stdin:83: trailing whitespace.

warning: 3 lines add whitespace errors.
```

Than I have to go through the code by my own. The conflict are always older changes done by me in "my-feature" branch and a later version of the same line. It looks like rebase somehow confuses the order of the commits, I don't know.

After I fixed it I mark them as fixed (`git add`) and call `git rebase --continue` which leads again to a similar error. Than I have to repeat this steps multiple times until the rebase process is finished.

In master there where no changes on the files I edited in the "my-feature" branch. So I would think that a rebase should go through without any conflicts. Just pull in all the other changes, and apply my changes in the right order on top of it.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are tired to resolve the same conflicts again and again you can enable rerere: 'git config --global rerere.enabled true'

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't sound like a conflict, it sounds like someone added a commit hook that detects whitespace errors.

When you rebase, your feature-branch commits get replayed one-by-one. So, the fact that you subsequently fixed a whitespace error won't stop git complaining while it's replaying the older commit.

Either use rebase to squash your commits down, so you don't have the bad commits in your history, or just stop rebasing. You could merge `master -> my-feature` to keep your branch up-to-date, and then merge back only when you're done.

Comment: Commit hook? He rebases locally.

Comment: Yeah, and rebase is creating local commits. I didn't say a _push_ hook.

Comment: Most likely a client-side pre-commit hook, from the sound of it. OP could inspect `.git/hooks/*` to check if that's where the errors are coming from.

Comment: In fact, this sounds like the behaviour of the sample hook which ships as `.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample` ... check to see if that's been renamed to `pre-commit` and is executable.

Comment: but client-side hooks are local and can't be updated by pull, can they?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes git gives warning on whitespaces. If in your files the whitespace is not significant you can skip these warnings with this configuration:

```
 git config --global apply.whitespace nowarn
```

If you prefer not to change your git configuration you can use the option while doing the rebase:

```
 git rebase --ignore-whitespace
```